# Why do i need another $() after using .children for .modal to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering why i have to do this:

`$($("body").children("div")[0]).modal('show');`

instead of

`$("body").children("div")[0].modal('show');`

Doesn't the function `.children` give back a list with nodes? I am new to jquery and not that experienced yet with javascript so i was just wondering what the difference is.

`.modal` is a bootstrap function in case anyone was wondering.

Here is the context for completeness:

```
'click .edit': function (e, value, row, index) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php?controller=" + controller + "&action=edit&id=" + row['id'] + "&type=modal",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result !== null) {
                $("body").prepend(result);
                $($("body").children("div")[0]).modal('show');
            } else {
                alert("There was a problem with editing. Please contact a system admin or try again.");
            }
        }
    });
    e.stopPropagation();
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `("div")[0]` will return a dom element., which doesnt have jquery functions associated in it. Inorder to associate jquery functions to that element, you need to convert it again to jquery element by warping the `$()`

Other option is to use `eq()` operator like this,

`$("body").children("div:eq(0)").modal('show');`

Answer (score 2):

The returned element is a javascript DOM element which is not wrapped by any jQuery function. Hence you have to wrap it with another `$` mark. If you want to get the first element, use `$("body").children("div").first()` this will get you the first element as a jQuery object where you can use all the jQuery function.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation but i liked the answer of Anoop a bit more because he gave me some insight in what selectors are, so i selected his answer.